# How do I make gpg2 skip file instead of asking for password?

Tags: linux, gnupg

```
$ DISPLAY= gpg2 --yes --batch --no-tty < file.gpg
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Enter passphrase                                    │
│                                                     │
│                                                     │
│ Passphrase ________________________________________ │
│                                                     │
│                                                     │
|       <OK>                             <Cancel>     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Without `DISPLAY=` it shows GUI window instead. In any case it waits for input, interrupting a loop.

How do I make gpg2 only use gpg-agent and never interrupt processing to ask anything?

Supplying fake `--passphrase` makes remove key from agent.

Comment: don't put a passphase on the key in the first place? What problem are you actually trying to solve, unencrypting a large number of files?

Comment: Yes, recrypting a large number of files, some of which are corrupted or unrelated.

Comment: Note that this is in fact _gpg-agent_ showing the password prompts. Possibly gpg forgets to forward the "quiet mode" options when requesting decryption.

Comment: Yes, `gpg-agent --batch` inhibits prompts. But I cannot enter even the first passphrase then, which is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the pinentry loopback mode in `gpg-agent.conf` and use `--pinentry-mode cancel` (or `error`, depending on your requirements) as argument for GnuPG. This will loop back demanding the passphrase to GnuPG instead to some frontend pinentry implementation, and then return an error to `gpg-agent` simulating the cancel button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: don't use gpg-agent at all, use `--passphrase-file` instead:

```
killall gpg-agent
gpg2 -q --batch --no-tty --passphrase-file=/tmp/passphrase --decrypt file.gpg
```